# PostgreSQL, SQL: Compare values in one column in the table and return multiple columns by the condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a few rows.
I need to check: if all the values in the column index are equal then get three columns with unique values,
If values are not equal then get an empty table.
For example if index are equal:
Input

```
index   Product Version
10        A      2.5
10        A      2.5  
10        A      2.5
```

Output

```
index   Product Version
10        A      2.5
```

For example if index are not  equal:
Input:

```
index   Product      Version
10          A          2.5
11          B          3.3
10          A          2.5
10          A          2.5
```

Output

```
index   Product      Version
```

I tried to do that with "Case When" statement, but "Case When" can return only single column.
Is there a way to compare values in a column and return several columns?

Comment: . . Your question would be clearer if you had an example that returned more than one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: all records equal](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1b7e8ecac64c69fd0579b742e2659770)

[demo: records not equal](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c015fdf6e3209533cb46e5883a44b5ab)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY index, product, version),
        count(*) OVER ()
    FROM mytable
) s
WHERE row_number = count
```

Add a row count to each column group. If all records equal, the maximum row count equals the all-over record count.

So just return the record which have the same row number as the total count. If not all records equal, this record would not exist and return an empty table.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . this may be what you are thinking:

```
select distinct index, product, version
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.index <> t.index
                 );
```